# Randomly choose directories in PC using Python

Tags: python, random, directory, copy

I'm using python 2.x and I don't know how to make my script randomly choose directories in the same PC to copy files. It's quite important because it is for my final project.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: ok. i already posted it. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) package

```
In [1]: import tempfile


In [2]: print([f for f in dir(tempfile) if not f.startswith('_')])
['NamedTemporaryFile', 'SpooledTemporaryFile', 'TMP_MAX', 'TemporaryFile', 'gettempdir', 'gettempprefix', 'mkdtemp', 'mkstemp', 'mktemp', 'tempdir', 'template']

In [3]: help(tempfile.mkdtemp)
Help on function mkdtemp in module tempfile:

mkdtemp(suffix='', prefix='tmp', dir=None)
    User-callable function to create and return a unique temporary
    directory.  The return value is the pathname of the directory.

    Arguments are as for mkstemp, except that the 'text' argument is
    not accepted.

    The directory is readable, writable, and searchable only by the
    creating user.

    Caller is responsible for deleting the directory when done with it.
```